# How to match a possible null parameter in Mockito

Tags: mockito

I'm trying to verify that the class I'm testing calls the correct dependency class's method. So I'm trying to match the method parameters, but I don't really care about the actual values in this test, because I don't want to make my test brittle.

However, I'm running into trouble setting it up because Mockito has decided that the behaviour I'm expecting is a bug: https://github.com/mockito/mockito/issues/134

So what't the correct way to define an `ArgumentMatcher` for a parameter that might be `null`?

With issue #134 "fixed", this code fails because the matchers only match in the first case. How can I define a matcher to work in all 4 cases?

```
MyClass c = mock(MyClass.class);

c.foo("hello", "world");
c.foo("hello", null);
c.foo(null, "world");
c.foo(null, null);

verify(c, times(4)).foo(anyString(), anyString());
```

Answer (score 130, accepted):

From the javadocs of `any()`

> **Since Mockito 2.1.0**, only allow non-null `String`. As this
>   is a nullable reference, the suggested API to **match**
>   `null` wrapper would be `isNull()`. We felt this
>   change would make tests harness much safer that it was with Mockito
>   1.x.

So, the way to match nullable string arguments is explicit declaration:

```
nullable(String.class)
```

Comment: I believe this is the correct answer, not the one suggesting "any(String.class)".

Comment: it works perfectly! Thanks.  `public static <T> T nullable(Class<T> clazz)`
Argument that is either null or of the given type. reference from documents : https://javadoc.io/static/org.mockito/mockito-core/3.1.0/org/mockito/ArgumentMatchers.html#nullable-java.lang.Class-

Comment: and to match only null woth other matechers ,Mockito.isNull()

Answer (score 3):

I got this to work by switching to `any(String.class)`

I find this a bit misleading, because the API seems to suggest that `anyString()` is just an alias for `any(String.class)` at least up till the 2.0 update. To be fair, the documentation does specify that `anyString()` only matches non-null strings. It just seems counter-intuitive to me.

Comment: This seems to be the right answer from Mockito 2.0 onwards.  In versions of Mockito before 2.0, your original code using `anyString()` would have worked, but this is a breaking change that the Mockito team introduced with 2.0.

Comment: This does not work anymore. From documentation - ```Since Mockito 2.1.0 this method will perform a type check thus <code>null</code> values are not authorized```

Comment: I would agree with the last comment, this answer is not correct.  The previous answer recommending "nullable(String.class)" is likely the correct answer. I confirmed this in my own testing with v2.15.0.

Answer (score 0):

Because you configured `anyString()` but you pass by null value. The `anyString()` doesn't allow using null with `anyString()`, use `nullable(String.class)` allows the parameters can be null.

Replace your code by:

```
verify(c, times(4)).foo(nullable(String.class), nullable(String.class));
```

Answer (score -2):

How about:

```
verify(c, times(4)).foo(anyObject(), anyObject());
```

Does that work for you?

Matchers.anyObject() allows for `null`s.

Reference in [Mockito docs](http://site.mockito.org/mockito/docs/1.10.19/org/mockito/Matchers.html#anyObject()):

Comment: No, because then my IDE complains that `foo(String, String)` cannot be invoked by `foo(Object, Object)`

Comment: You could probably just use the type capturing `any()` but `anyObject` returns `Object` and so can't work.