# Mocking methods having parameters

Tags: java, mockito

I'm trying to mock an instance of a class using Mockito spy.
I read [this blog article](https://stevenschwenke.de/spyingWithMockito) possibly outdated to test if the depicted behaviour is real, but it does not quite do what I was expecting. Here is an Short Self Contained (In)Correct Example:

```
import org.mockito.Mockito;

import static org.mockito.Mockito.doReturn;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;

public class Sandbox {

    static class Foo {
        // nothing
    }

    public static class Subject {

        public int doStuffNoParameters() {
            System.out.println("doStuffNoParameters called");
            return -1;
        }

        public int doStuff(Foo f, String s) {
            System.out.println("doStuff called!");
            return 42;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Subject s = new Subject();
        final Subject mock = Mockito.spy(s);

        System.out.println((mock.doStuffNoParameters())); // expected doStuffNoParameters , -1
        // mock method with no parameters using when or doReturn
        doReturn(1).when(mock).doStuffNoParameters();
        System.out.println(mock.doStuffNoParameters()); // expected 1
        when(mock.doStuffNoParameters()).thenReturn(1);
        System.out.println(mock.doStuffNoParameters()); // expected 1

        // mock method with no parameters using when or doReturn
        doReturn(1).when(mock).doStuff(Mockito.any(Foo.class), Mockito.anyString());
        System.out.println(mock.doStuff(null, null)); // expected 1, got doStuff called then 42
        when(mock.doStuff(Mockito.any(Foo.class), Mockito.any(String.class))).thenReturn(1); // expected nothing, got doStuffCalled
        System.out.println(mock.doStuff(null, "anyway")); // expected 1; got doStuff called then 42

    }
}
```

Output is:

```
doStuffNoParameters called
-1
1
1
doStuff called!
42
doStuff called!
doStuff called!
42
```

Expected output is in the code. In particular, I'd like to know how I can mock call to functions with parameters when the parameters of the function call might not be available, be from a different instance or null when writting the mock behaviour.
**EDIT** Using mockito v2.28.2

Comment: I got this output doStuffNoParameters called
-1
1
1
1
1

Comment: Thanks for trying out @dreamcrash . Might be a version problem which are you using ? I'm using 2.28.2

Comment: <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.4</version>

Comment: same version, same results as you @dreamcrash. I think in newer version any(Clazz.class) does not match when called with null though

Comment: Would this help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40225011/how-to-match-a-possible-null-parameter-in-mockito

Comment: Yes, that's what I was looking for :) Thanks @dreamcrash

Answer (score 0):

The expected behaviour is achieved when calling `nullable(Clazz.class)` instead of `any` as highlighted in the comments by dreamcrash and in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40225011/how-to-match-a-possible-null-parameter-in-mockito)