# Spring Boot JUnit5 Mokito when thenReturn not working

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit5

**UPDATE**

Weirdly my test is passing when I am setting `String token = ""` instead of `String token = null` in my controller.

Mokito is returning the default value `null` instead of `OK` string. So my test is failing with NPE.

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "String.toLowerCase()" because "result" is null
```

My test method:

```
@WebMvcTest(ClusterController.class)
class ClusterControllerTest {
    
        @Autowired
        private MockMvc mockMvc;
    
        @MockBean
        private ClusterService clusterService;
    
        @MockBean
        private ClusterRestService clusterRestService;

        @Test
        void testPatchTestClusterVM() throws Exception {     

        //Given
        when(clusterService.startPatchingTest(any(), anyString(), anyString(), anyString())).thenReturn("OK");
        
        //When
        RequestBuilder request = MockMvcRequestBuilders
                .post("/patch/clustertest/mycluster/host/vc2crtp1770461np")
                .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
        
        //Then
        mockMvc.perform(request)
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andReturn();       
    }
```

My Controller method:

```
@PostMapping("/patch/clustertest/{clustername}/host/{hostname}")
    public ResponseEntity<?> patchClusterTestVM(@PathVariable("clustername") String clusterName, @PathVariable("hostname") String hostName) {
        String token = null;
        String uuid = UUID.randomUUID().toString();     
        String result = clusterService.startPatchingTest(new ClusterDetailsClass(1L, "mycluster"), hostName, token, uuid);
        return new ResponseEntity<String>(result.toLowerCase(), HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

Application Test:

```
@SpringBootTest
class MyApplicationTests {

    @Test
    void contextLoads() {
    }

}
```

Comment: How did you initialize the mock 'clusterService'  and is it injected into the controller?

Comment: It is added as a mock bean. `@MockBean
 private ClusterService clusterService;`

Comment: Did you put @ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class) on the test class?

Comment: Weirdly my test is passing when I am setting `String token = ""` instead of `String token = null` in my controller.

Comment: Maybe try to replace anyString() with any() for the token parameter?

Comment: Updated test class details. replacing anyString() with any() is also not working,

Comment: The `any*` from Mockito don't match `null` (this has changed for quite some time now). You now have to use the more explicit, `nullable()` instead.

Comment: @M.Deinum It worked. I used `nullable(String.class)` instead of `anyString()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[ArgumentMatchers#anyString](https://javadoc.io/doc/org.mockito/mockito-core/5.4.0/org/mockito/ArgumentMatchers.html#anyString()) matches any **non-null** string, so the following stub only applies to non-null tokens:

```
when(clusterService.startPatchingTest(any(), anyString(), anyString(), anyString())).thenReturn("OK");
```

This explains why Mockito only returns "OK" when the token is non-null (e.g. an empty string). If the token is `null`, the argument is not matched, causing Mockito to return the default value (`null`).

If you're using Mockito 2.1.0 or later, you should use `nullable(String.class)` to match nullable strings, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42024167/12220563), otherwise you should use `any()`.

Answer (score -1):

You did not show all the relevant code like the test class annotations and how the clusterservice is initialized and injected. This should work I think:

```
@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
class ClusterTest {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @MockBean
    private ClusterService clusterService;

    @Test
    void testPatchTestClusterVM() throws Exception {     

        //Given
        when(clusterService.startPatchingTest(any(), anyString(), anyString(), anyString())).thenReturn("OK");
```

Comment: This won't solve a thing, nor would you need `@ExtendWith` when using `@SpringBootTest`.

Comment: I was looking in the direction of the test class setup and mock init, which OP did not share initially. Apparently that was not the cause, but the behavior of the argumentmatchers. Good that you spotted that.

Comment: That wouldn't lead to a nullpointer on the mocks return value but a nullpointer elsewhere.

Comment: You are right. I didn't read the question well enough.

Answer (score -1):

You're returning a String and not a ResponseEntity.

Try

```
//Given
ResponseEntity okReturn = new ResponseEntity<String>("result", HttpStatus.OK)
when(clusterService.startPatchingTest(any(), anyString(), anyString(), anyString())).thenReturn(okReturn);
```